# Replace tab between names with a space

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How can I get rid of that tab with regular expressions? I also need to do it on the fly because the name will be inside a list.

```
import re
x = 'Muh    kay'
```

I want x to be

```
x = 'Muh Kay'
```

with only one space between them.

Comment: Create a regex that identifies tabs and replace it with a space

Comment: Why do you need regular expressions? Split the string, then rejoin it on a space

Comment: Why would you use regex to replace a specific character with another specific character? Just use `str.replace`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27750852/7311767

Comment: Do you want to replace the tab in the value of `x`, or in the source code itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this re.sub(r'\t', ' ', s) which will replace tabs with space.
Please refer this answer: [How to replace custom tabs with spaces in a string, depend on the size of the tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052862/how-to-replace-custom-tabs-with-spaces-in-a-string-depend-on-the-size-of-the-ta)

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
x = 'Muh    kay'   
x = ' '.join(i.capitalize() for i in x.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

`x.replace('\t', ' ')`

However, this won't add the capital letter as the example shows.